Do Apple photos sync with Google Photos edits?
I have a lot of images that I’ve edited in the Google Photos app (mostly applying filters such as Dynamic and Enhance).
Does the photos in the iOS photo/camera app sync with the Google Photos edits? Ordinarily, I’d think no, but I checked a photo I made a small saturation edit to and it appears to have synced.
